# KNeighborsClassifier from sklearn.neighbors import error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, python-import, sklearn-pandas

guys am having import error while trying to import KNeighborsClassifier from sklearn.neighbors import k

its showing the following errors

ImportError: cannot import name 'kNeighborsClassifier' from 'sklearn.neighbors' (/home/themysteriouschemeng/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/**init**.py)

Comment: Trying to edit the *answer* in order to add (images of) your code is the absolutely wrong thing to do here and not how SO works. Please edit your own question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have used small `k` instead of capital `K` in `KNeighborsClassifier`.

Your import -`from sklearn.neighbors import kNeighborsClassifier`

Right import - `from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`

Replace small `k` with capital `K` in `KNeighborsClassifier` and this will fix your import issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code you are using?

Btw the basic code to import is

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
```

Comment: from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier                                                            it shows the following errorImportError: cannot import name 'kNeighborsClassifier' from 'sklearn.neighbors' (/home/themysteriouschemeng/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/__init__.py)